# PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in _registry_check_code()

Tags: database, drush

Drush is running on MAMP, PHP 5.6.6.

Inside `/Volumes/Doxy/htdocs/omegadoen/sites/all/themes/omega`

I run:

```
drush omega-wizard
```

I get:

> ## Additional uncaught exception thrown while handling
>   exception.
>
> ### Original
>
> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]
>   [2002] No such file or directory in drupal_is_denied() (line 1917 of
>   /Volumes/Doxy/htdocs/omegadoen/includes/bootstrap.inc).
>
> ### Additional
>
> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in
>   _registry_check_code() (line 3169 of /Volumes/Doxy/htdocs/omegadoen/includes/bootstrap.inc).
>
> ---
>
> Drush
>   command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.   [error]

What now?

Comment: OS X sometimes gets the mysql.sock location wrong if you're using MAMP, which can lead to confusing errors like you're experiencing. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219970/warning-mysql-connect-2002-no-such-file-or-directory-trying-to-connect-vi

Answer (score 26):

For simplicity check `drush status` with verbose and debug parameters:

```
drush -vd status
```

If you're using different profile, don't forget to include it as `-l http://foo`.

If you still have a problem, it's an issue with bootstrapping your Drupal.

First check your SQL connection if it's working:

```
drush sql-cli
```

If it does not, check your db credentials in your Drupal settings file.

If it does, there is a problem with SQL connection through the socket.

So in MAMP you've to do:

1. Check value of `socket` in my.cnf (menu: *File/Edit Template*), it's usually set as:

   ```
   socket      = /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
   ```
2. Double check if your MySQL can find this file:

   ```
   $ mysql_config --socket
   /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
   ```
3. Double check if your PHP has the right `mysql.sock` set-up:

   ```
   $ php -i | grep mysql.default_socket
   ```
4. Link the socket into your `/tmp` and see if that helps:

   ```
   sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql /var/mysql
   ```
5. Test the socket file:

   ```
   mysql --socket=/var/mysql/mysql.sock
   ```
6. Still the problem? Add the following setting into your `$databases`:

   ```
   $databases['default']['default'] = array(
     // ...
     'unix_socket' => '/var/mysql/mysql.sock',
   ```

---

#### Troubleshooting

- Try: `drush sqlq "SELECT @@version_comment LIMIT 1"`
- Try: `drush ev "Database::getConnection('default', 'default');"`
- Try: `mysql --socket=$(php -r 'echo ini_get("mysql.default_socket");')`
- Check permissions on Unix socket: `stat $(mysql_config --socket)`
- Debug: on OS X with `sudo dtruss -fn mysqld`, on Linux with `strace`
- Debug with XDebug:

  - `echo '<?php xdebug_start_trace("/tmp/foo.log");' > init.php`
  - `drush -c init.php ev 'Database::getConnection("default", "default");'`
  - or set `xdebug.show_exception_trace=1` in your `xdebug.ini`
- Check MySQL settings:

  - `echo '<?php phpinfo();' > init.php`
  - `drush -c init.php  ev 'Database::getConnection("default", "default");' | grep mysql`
- Run: `php -r "new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;charset=utf8;dbname=dbname', 'root', 'root');"`
- Try to [rebuilt your registry](https://www.drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild)

Comment: wow. this is a *very* complete answer.  Surprised there are not more upvotes on this. Thanks.

Comment: I'd upvote this answer on all of the other "drush" "mamp"  "mysql" related questions here on stack exchange, just so its easier to find... many of the other ones have really incomplete answers.

Comment: So I don't have this file `/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock` nor this file `/var/mysql/mysql.sock` using MAMP. I can connect to phpMyAdmin no problem though..weird. Whenever I try `drush cr` I get the sql connection issue. I can `drush sql-sync` just fine though...

Comment: Absolutely brilliant answer. This is a very complete answer on a topic that is really obfuscated partly because of different set ups people are using and also a lack of understanding of how mysql works under the hood (at least on my behalf).

Comment: Just wanted to comment that this also solves similar issues with drupal console.

Comment: coming back nearly 3 years later with a new machine and this again solved my problem. I was wrong in my original comment from 2016. tmp is a hidden folder -_- I wish I could upvote again

Comment: This should be in the official Drush documenation. This is the best troubleshooting checklist I have found.